# What is recommended way for changing data before saving state of store

Tags: redux, flux, ngrx-store

I need to change the payload before saving to the state.

### 1. Before `Action`

```
const origin = [1, 2, 3];
const changed = origin.map(value => value * 10);
store.dispatch(new Action(changed));
```

### 2. `Action`

```
const origin = [1, 2, 3];
store.dispatch(new action(origin));    

Action.constructor(payload){
  this.payload = payload.map(value => value * 10);
}
```

### 3. `Reducer`

```
const origin = [1, 2, 3];
store.dispatch(new Action(origin));    

function reducer(type, payload){
    // ...
    payload = payload.map(value => value * 10);
    // ...
}
```

This example code is just an example.

It will have many codes for real, and `Action` can be called from multiple places.

I'm already using reducer for little process, but if need to many steps, I'm confused whether `reducer` is appropriate.

What is the recommended way?

Comment: Just send the appropriate payload to the reducer

Comment: @bugs did your answer means to the data processing before dispatch action?

Comment: Exactly. That's definitely the cleanest way